# Dominated Convergence Theorem - need complete measure?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

Here is the theorem I was reading: (p54, Folland)

> $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ is a measure space. Let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence in $L^1(\mu)$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e and exists $g \in L^1(\mu)$ such that $|f_n| \le g$ for all $n$. Then $f \in L^1 (\mu)$ and $\int f = \lim \int f_n $.

How do we know $f$ is measurable? We know $g:=\limsup f_n$ is measurable, and $g=f$ a.e. But for $f$ to be measurable do we not need complete measure?

Comment: To tell whether this is a technical inconsequential error, or not an error at all, one would have to read Folland's particular definitions carefully.

Comment: Actually I added the first line "$(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a measure space" myself. But the theorem doesn't hold if $\mu$ is not complete right?

Comment: That depends on how $L^1(\mu)$ is defined.

Comment: Folland defines it as "The set of equivalence classes of a.e. defined integrable functions on $X$."

Comment: Leaving aside the category error ($f$ is a function, but the elements of $L^1(\mu)$ are sets of functions; but that's an almost universally used abuse of notation, the "correct" language is too cumbersome), the question is what types of function belong to the equivalence classes. If one looks at functions that are a.e. equal to a measurable function, then $f \in L^1(\mu)$ is [modulo the category issue, $[f] \in L^1(\mu)$ where $[f]$ is the equivalence class of $f$ would be completely correct] correct.

Comment: If only $\mathcal{M}$-measurable functions are considered, then, since for $\mu$-incomplete $\mathcal{M}$, we indeed have no guarantee that $f$ is $\mathcal{M}$-measurable, only that it is $\mu$-a.e. equal to such a function, we can't assert $f\in L^1(\mu)$ in general. But, as GEdgar said, even then it's an inconsequential glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard abuse as others have pointed out.

You should think of defining $f$ to be equal to the pointwise limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ wherever that limit exists and equal to anything you like, such as 0, when that limit does not exist. This will be a measurable function.

Or if you can stand it, $f$ is only defined almost everywhere. But then $f^{-1}(B) = \{x : f(x) \in B\}$ for a Borel set $B$ can only possibly be a subset of the set of points where $f$ is defined.